# Convert string-encoded list into new dataframe

Tags: python, list

I have a dataframe where in one column I have the following string-encoded list.
I would like to create new data frame with few new columns from it, for example:
Customer name, Cast_ID, Character.

```
[{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f95', 'gender': 2, 'id': 31, 'name': 'Tom Hanks', 'order': 0, 'profile_path': '/pQFoyx7rp09CJTAb932F2g8Nlho.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 15, 'character': 'Buzz Lightyear (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f99', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12898, 'name': 'Tim Allen', 'order': 1, 'profile_path': '/uX2xVf6pMmPepxnvFWyBtjexzgY.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 16, 'character': 'Mr. Potato Head (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f9d', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7167, 'name': 'Don Rickles', 'order': 2, 'profile_path': '/h5BcaDMPRVLHLDzbQavec4xfSdt.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 17, 'character': 'Slinky Dog (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa1', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12899, 'name': 'Jim Varney', 'order': 3, 'profile_path': '/eIo2jVVXYgjDtaHoF19Ll9vtW7h.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 18, 'character': 'Rex (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa5', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12900, 'name': 'Wallace Shawn', 'order': 4, 'profile_path': '/oGE6JqPP2xH4tNORKNqxbNPYi7u.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 19, 'character': 'Hamm (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa9', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7907, 'name': 'John Ratzenberger', 'order': 5, 'profile_path': '/yGechiKWL6TJDfVE2KPSJYqdMsY.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 20, 'character': 'Bo Peep (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fad', 'gender': 1, 'id': 8873, 'name': 'Annie Potts', 'order': 6, 'profile_path': '/eryXT84RL41jHSJcMy4kS3u9y6w.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 26, 'character': 'Andy (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fc1', 'gender': 0, 'id': 1116442, 'name': 'John Morris', 'order': 7, 'profile_path': '/vYGyvK4LzeaUCoNSHtsuqJUY15M.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 22, 'character': 'Sid (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb1', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12901, 'name': 'Erik von Detten', 'order': 8, 'profile_path': '/twnF1ZaJ1FUNUuo6xLXwcxjayBE.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 23, 'character': 'Mrs. Davis (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb5', 'gender': 1, 'id': 12133, 'name': 'Laurie Metcalf', 'order': 9, 'profile_path': '/unMMIT60eoBM2sN2nyR7EZ2BvvD.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 24, 'character': 'Sergeant (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb9', 'gender': 2, 'id': 8655, 'name': 'R. Lee Ermey', 'order': 10, 'profile_path': '/r8GBqFBjypLUP9VVqDqfZ7wYbSs.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 25, 'character': 'Hannah (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fbd', 'gender': 1, 'id': 12903, 'name': 'Sarah Freeman', 'order': 11, 'profile_path': None}, {'cast_id': 27, 'character': 'TV Announcer (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fc5', 'gender': 2, 'id': 37221, 'name': 'Penn Jillette', 'order': 12, 'profile_path': '/zmAaXUdx12NRsssgHbk1T31j2x9.jpg'}]
```

I started by splitting:

```
new_cast = credits['cast'].str.split(',')
```

but have no idea where to move from there.

Comment: If my assumption is false in my answer below please update your question to clarify and comment on my answer so I can update.

Comment: What do you get if you do `credits['cast']` without the `str` part?

Comment: getting error without the str part, there is no attribute split

Comment: See my edit on my answer below.

Comment: @Sylwi If you do a `credits.shape` what do you get? If you do a `credits['cast'].shape` what do you get?

Comment: for the credits.shape I got: (45476, 4), for the credits['cast'].shape : (45476,)

Comment: @Sylwi Sorry, I was not being clear, I meant what does `credits['cast']` return, without `.str.split(',')`. To me it looks like an unnecessary step to make it a string before continuing.

Comment: yes, I agree I trashed that idea, I came back to the original df credits, for sure the data in column 'cast' is string, but when I pass that json command you mentioned it gives me the error as before: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Series

Comment: maybe I am doing something wrong when assigning variable? I have done the following: var = credits['cast'] and then pass this var into var = json.loads(var.replace("'",'"').replace("None", '"None"'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your variable is a string.

```py
var_str = "[{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f95', 'gender': 2, 'id': 31, 'name': 'Tom Hanks', 'order': 0, 'profile_path': '/pQFoyx7rp09CJTAb932F2g8Nlho.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 15, 'character': 'Buzz Lightyear (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f99', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12898, 'name': 'Tim Allen', 'order': 1, 'profile_path': '/uX2xVf6pMmPepxnvFWyBtjexzgY.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 16, 'character': 'Mr. Potato Head (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f9d', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7167, 'name': 'Don Rickles', 'order': 2, 'profile_path': '/h5BcaDMPRVLHLDzbQavec4xfSdt.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 17, 'character': 'Slinky Dog (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa1', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12899, 'name': 'Jim Varney', 'order': 3, 'profile_path': '/eIo2jVVXYgjDtaHoF19Ll9vtW7h.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 18, 'character': 'Rex (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa5', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12900, 'name': 'Wallace Shawn', 'order': 4, 'profile_path': '/oGE6JqPP2xH4tNORKNqxbNPYi7u.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 19, 'character': 'Hamm (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa9', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7907, 'name': 'John Ratzenberger', 'order': 5, 'profile_path': '/yGechiKWL6TJDfVE2KPSJYqdMsY.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 20, 'character': 'Bo Peep (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fad', 'gender': 1, 'id': 8873, 'name': 'Annie Potts', 'order': 6, 'profile_path': '/eryXT84RL41jHSJcMy4kS3u9y6w.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 26, 'character': 'Andy (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fc1', 'gender': 0, 'id': 1116442, 'name': 'John Morris', 'order': 7, 'profile_path': '/vYGyvK4LzeaUCoNSHtsuqJUY15M.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 22, 'character': 'Sid (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb1', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12901, 'name': 'Erik von Detten', 'order': 8, 'profile_path': '/twnF1ZaJ1FUNUuo6xLXwcxjayBE.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 23, 'character': 'Mrs. Davis (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb5', 'gender': 1, 'id': 12133, 'name': 'Laurie Metcalf', 'order': 9, 'profile_path': '/unMMIT60eoBM2sN2nyR7EZ2BvvD.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 24, 'character': 'Sergeant (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb9', 'gender': 2, 'id': 8655, 'name': 'R. Lee Ermey', 'order': 10, 'profile_path': '/r8GBqFBjypLUP9VVqDqfZ7wYbSs.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 25, 'character': 'Hannah (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fbd', 'gender': 1, 'id': 12903, 'name': 'Sarah Freeman', 'order': 11, 'profile_path': None}, {'cast_id': 27, 'character': 'TV Announcer (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fc5', 'gender': 2, 'id': 37221, 'name': 'Penn Jillette', 'order': 12, 'profile_path': '/zmAaXUdx12NRsssgHbk1T31j2x9.jpg'}]"
```

Use the json library to load it in. There are a few issues though. The library expects the quotes to be double quotes, and cannot treat the value None. So replace these with sensible values.

```py
var = json.loads(var_str.replace("'",'"').replace("None", '"None"'))
```

This produces the following variable:

```py
var = [{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f95', 'gender': 2, 'id': 31, 'name': 'Tom Hanks', 'order': 0, 'profile_path': '/pQFoyx7rp09CJTAb932F2g8Nlho.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 15, 'character': 'Buzz Lightyear (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f99', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12898, 'name': 'Tim Allen', 'order': 1, 'profile_path': '/uX2xVf6pMmPepxnvFWyBtjexzgY.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 16, 'character': 'Mr. Potato Head (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f9d', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7167, 'name': 'Don Rickles', 'order': 2, 'profile_path': '/h5BcaDMPRVLHLDzbQavec4xfSdt.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 17, 'character': 'Slinky Dog (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa1', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12899, 'name': 'Jim Varney', 'order': 3, 'profile_path': '/eIo2jVVXYgjDtaHoF19Ll9vtW7h.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 18, 'character': 'Rex (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa5', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12900, 'name': 'Wallace Shawn', 'order': 4, 'profile_path': '/oGE6JqPP2xH4tNORKNqxbNPYi7u.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 19, 'character': 'Hamm (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa9', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7907, 'name': 'John Ratzenberger', 'order': 5, 'profile_path': '/yGechiKWL6TJDfVE2KPSJYqdMsY.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 20, 'character': 'Bo Peep (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fad', 'gender': 1, 'id': 8873, 'name': 'Annie Potts', 'order': 6, 'profile_path': '/eryXT84RL41jHSJcMy4kS3u9y6w.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 26, 'character': 'Andy (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fc1', 'gender': 0, 'id': 1116442, 'name': 'John Morris', 'order': 7, 'profile_path': '/vYGyvK4LzeaUCoNSHtsuqJUY15M.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 22, 'character': 'Sid (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb1', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12901, 'name': 'Erik von Detten', 'order': 8, 'profile_path': '/twnF1ZaJ1FUNUuo6xLXwcxjayBE.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 23, 'character': 'Mrs. Davis (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb5', 'gender': 1, 'id': 12133, 'name': 'Laurie Metcalf', 'order': 9, 'profile_path': '/unMMIT60eoBM2sN2nyR7EZ2BvvD.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 24, 'character': 'Sergeant (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb9', 'gender': 2, 'id': 8655, 'name': 'R. Lee Ermey', 'order': 10, 'profile_path': '/r8GBqFBjypLUP9VVqDqfZ7wYbSs.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 25, 'character': 'Hannah (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fbd', 'gender': 1, 'id': 12903, 'name': 'Sarah Freeman', 'order': 11, 'profile_path': 'None'}, {'cast_id': 27, 'character': 'TV Announcer (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fc5', 'gender': 2, 'id': 37221, 'name': 'Penn Jillette', 'order': 12, 'profile_path': '/zmAaXUdx12NRsssgHbk1T31j2x9.jpg'}]
```

Then pass this to pandas:

```py
pd.DataFrame(var)
```

which results in a dataframe with 13 rows and 8 columns named: `cast_id`, `character`, `credit_id`, `gender`, `id`, `name`, `order`, `profile_path`.

You can then find all instances of None and replace those with Nulls as and if required.

Edit: You say your string is in a series. I'm assuming `s = pd.Series(var_str)` reproduces your variable. In this case you can simply select the first element `var_str = s[0]` to obtain the variable I had and apply the same processing. If you have multiple rows of string encoded lists, I suggest you do something like this:

```py
s.apply(lambda x: json.loads(var_str.replace("'",'"').replace("None", '"None"')))
```

This will produce a series of dictionaries witch you can then loop over and convert to DataFrames.

Comment: 0        ["[{'id': 16", " 'name': 'Animation'}", " {'id...
1        ["[{'id': 12", " 'name': 'Adventure'}", " {'id...

45463    ["[{'id': 28", " 'name': 'Action'}", " {'id': ...
45464                                               ['[]']
45465                                               ['[]']
Name: genres, Length: 45466, dtype: object

Comment: Please type out a line of code in python that will re-produce the variable and add that to your question. e.g. `pd.Series(["{'something': 'else'}", "{'isit': 'this'}"])`

Comment: Does this series have more than 1 element or is it just 1 element as a long string?

Comment: I have followed your steps above, and apply the lambda function, seems that all worked. I am gonna try to loop over, but never done that before. :-), fingers crossed.

Comment: take a look at this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html to help with that

Comment: I have done the following loop: for key, value in var.items() :
    print(key + " : " + str(value)) but error says 'str' object has no attribute 'items', any idea what went wrong?

Comment: It is very difficult to help you without a piece of code that runs on its own that reproduces the problem. I suggest you create that (in as few lines as possible) and post a new question. You are welcome to then link it here and I will try to answer.

Comment: my new var - what type it should have? after running that lambda function? It has string now.