# loop over series of dictionaries to convert to DataFrames

Tags: python, loops

I have that list of dictionaries in several rows that I need to loop over to create new DataFrame.
I have tried the following loop:

```
 for key, value in s.items():

    print(key + " : " + str(value))
```

but getting the following error:   unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

The type of my s: pandas.core.series.Series

[Convert string-encoded list into new dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67382995/convert-string-encoded-list-into-new-dataframe/67383147?noredirect=1#comment119128839_67383147)

s:

```
0        [{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)',...
1        [{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)',...
2        [{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)',...
45474    [{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)',...
45475    [{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)',...
Name: cast, Length: 45476, dtype: object
```

Comment: If I have correctly read your post, `s` is a `Series` of `objects`. But the actual type of those objects matters. What give `type(s.iloc[0])`? (said differently is is a list or dicts or a string?)

Comment: @ Serge Ballest, yes, type(s.iloc[0]) it is string.... how can I modify the loop to make this work?

Comment: You can easily get rid of the error with `print(key, ':', value)` or `print(str(key) + ' : ' + str(value))`. But I assume that you want to do something else with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the related post and your comment, I assume that you have a pandas Series (of a column from a DataFrame which is the same) containing string representations of lists of dicts.

Conceptualy what should be done will use the following conversions:

- string -> list of dicts: I would use `ast.literal_eval`
- list(s) of dicts -> DataFrame(s) -> a DataFrame can directly be created from a list of dicts.

So you could build a list of DataFrames, one per row of your Series that way:

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(d)) for d in s]
```

you could even concatenate all of them in one single dataframe:

```
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

or directly build the full dataframe with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([d for elt in s for d in ast.literal_eval(elt)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you are looping over strings and not dictionaries. Could you be a bit more specific as to how your data looks?

EDIT: probably not the best way to do it but:

```
for d in s:
    for key, value in d.items():
        print(key + ": " + str(value))
```

Comment: I think it is caused because you loop over the index of the series and not the dictionaries in the series when using 'key', which is an int.

Comment: how should I modify my loop?